# MongoDB Community : Error when installing service as local or domain user

Tags: mongodb

When installing MongoDB Community as a local service you need to enter the future credentials of your account :

[image]

If I enter for example:
user: `MongoDB`
password : `root`

I got this error message:

> The domain, user name and/or password are incorrect.
>   Remember to use "." for the domain if the account is on the local
>   machine.

[image: error]

What should I write here? Whenever I write something, I get an error.

Comment: Not sure why this question is closed? I think it is a valid question.

Comment: Do anyone have the solution for this?

Comment: Got the solution!! Go to that directory where you kept MogoDB installer. Open PowerShell or CMD as Administrator. And just Run the file using its name only. Same installer window will appear, but this time no error will be there. Worked for me.

Comment: the above solution is for the domain user, if you just want to install on your local machine even there is any domain configure, then leave the domain blank and give any username/password for example: admin/admin

Comment: It may appear that the MongoDB installer is asking for your credentials, it's actually Windows UAC enforcing its security checks before allowing the installation of the service.

Answer (score 71):

Here is the solution:
Username should be 'username' of your system/device.
And password should be password of your system/device.
It's weird, but that shall work.

Comment: I think you meant to add a screenshot?

Comment: and it works, but totally weird..

Comment: what if i dont have password for my system?

Comment: It only works , this answer should be accepted.

Comment: account Name should be username' of your system/device as well ( example on window 10,it's name of login user)

Comment: the above solution is for the domain user, if you just want to install on your local machine even there is any domain configure, then leave the domain blank and give any username/password for example: admin/admin

Comment: its look strange but the solution that worked for me to read the license scrolling fully down and then I selected default option.

Comment: it worked.. let the domain part as . (dot) itself and account name and password as window login id and its password. went to next screen without error popup.

Comment: I do not want to share my password with MongoDb. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 36):

Here's the solution for Windows 10(x64):

- If you don't have a domain (for home or personal computers), leave the domain field with "."
- If your computer is owned by your company, contact your system administrator and then in the domain field type : **Company_Domain**
- In the username field,

  - for personal computers : type your **username**. If you're signed in with a 
    Microsoft Account, type the email address or the name of your Microsoft Account.
  - for company provided machines : type your username as 
    **Company_Domain/Your_Username**
- In the password field type the **password** not the PIN number (if you've set it up).

That should help.

Comment: Thanks, works for me.

Comment: It worked for me too. PC Username and password for the account name and password.

Answer (score 3):

I had admin user without password.I had set password and try installation and give local admin user and password.it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best solution: Provide your system/device Username and password. And password should be password of your system/device. It's weird, but it shall work.

Answer (score 1):

quit intall . restart install msi file,and select default option

Answer (score 0):

I used the a similar solution as Khan.  I went to the download directory and when I executed the msi file this time, I was asked whether the Compass option should be installed.  After unchecking that, the rest of the install worked, using default options.  This is a Windows 10 laptop.